# Find the probability that a randomly chosen three digit number has exactly three factors

Tags: probability, number-theory

My textbook's solution:

Number of three digit numbers = 900

If a number has exactly three factors, then it must be square of a prime number.
Squares of 11,13,17,19,23,29,31 are three digit numbers.

Therefore, required probability = $\frac{7}{900}$

But, I think this solution is wrong because it doesn't include numbers like 143 = 1 * 11 * 13 and many others which are not squares of a prime number.

If the textbook solution is wrong, then how can I solve this problem.

Comment: $143$ has factors $\{1,11,13,143\}$.  You were right initially.  You need $p^2$, which has factors $\{1,p,p^2\}$.

Comment: Any number that has an odd number of factors is a square (you can pair all factors except the square root).

Comment: Thank You! Now I understand it